# What is the difference between accuracy and AUC score which one to trust?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, auc

I've 300 samples with multiclass classification problem with 3-classes. I implemented SVM in R programming. Below is the output which I am really confused. Can anyone logically explain to me what is happening with AUC score and accuracy?

```
library(e1071)
library(rpart)
library(mlbench)

svm.model <- svm(train$OVERBILL ~ ., data = train,cross = 10)
svm_pred <- predict(svm.model,test_features)
class(svm.model)
summary(svm.model)
print(svm.model)
table(pred = svm_pred, true = t(test_labels))
conf_matrix <- table(svm_pred, t(test_labels))
plotROC(svm_pred, test_labels)

library(MLmetrics)
Accuracy(svm_pred, test_labels)
AUC(svm_pred, test_labels)

>summary(svm.model)

Call:
svm(formula = train$OVERBILL ~ ., data = train, cross = 10)


Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.02173913 
    epsilon:  0.1 


Number of Support Vectors:  148



10-fold cross-validation on training data:

Total Mean Squared Error: 1.647486 
Squared Correlation Coefficient: 0.6529751 
Mean Squared Errors:
 3.458888 1.577432 0.944911 1.574407 0.1335981 1.01167 0.3062907 2.153197 4.406021 0.9293474
```

Confusion Matrix output

```
> conf_matrix <- table(svm_pred, t(test_labels))
> conf_matrix

svm_pred             0 1 6
  0.0745148876117468 1 0 0
  0.0999985783696893 2 0 0
  0.111467240126623  1 0 0
  0.126064180397959  1 0 0
  0.244978798581911  1 0 0
  0.475887420382214  1 0 0
  0.498646642602807  1 0 0
  0.591720283486985  1 0 0
  0.599232473099488  1 0 0
  0.62612033814901   1 0 0
  0.643312930663615  1 0 0
  0.653118546881599  1 0 0
  0.719254904953799  1 0 0
  0.721692119489509  0 1 0
  0.723267666375418  1 0 0
  0.723365970291335  3 1 0
  0.723366269162984  1 0 0
  0.723366418505045  0 1 0
  0.745038752158159  0 1 0
  0.761251850277529  0 1 0
  0.785262505543235  0 1 0
  0.788659460834314  0 1 0
  0.797535565182218  0 1 0
  0.800899932491485  0 1 0
  0.814008416261782  0 1 0
  0.837555080269472  0 1 0
  0.889990937504089  0 1 0
  0.890932813536095  0 1 0
  0.897365630569616  0 1 0
  0.899900271384598  0 1 0
  0.900072244535015  0 1 0
  0.901314988651768  0 1 0
  0.915466541503509  0 1 0
  0.930661659145462  0 1 0
  1.29917198580499   1 0 0
  1.72336597028937   0 0 1
  1.72343732250701   0 0 1
  2.80409843555754   0 0 1
  3.42511547417645   0 0 1
  3.92252405204058   0 0 1
  3.95924753259954   0 0 1
  4.28587842932451   0 0 1
  5.89954463445867   0 0 1
```

Output:

```
    > Accuracy(svm_pred, test_labels)
    [1] 0
    > AUC(svm_pred, test_labels)
    [1] 0.9302632
```

Comment: there is definitely something wrong with your code. Accuracy of 0 is pretty much not possible in classification with 3 possible class values.

And you should consider switching to a binary problem, if you want to understand Roc-curves (AUC) and accuracy, as this makes things much easier.
Reimplementing machine learning algorithms is good, but you should maybe not start with SVMs as they are a bit more advanced. decision trees and multivariate regression are easier to implement from scratch.

Comment: Can you show us the confusion matrix of predicted vs actual labels on the test set?

Comment: I will add more details

Comment: Accuracy has essentially no utility for comparing models or evaluating their quality. More info: http://www.fharrell.com/2017/03/damage-caused-by-classification.html

Comment: @Sycorax That blog post is about scoring rules and probabilistic classification. An SVM is a classifier, not a probabilistic classifier. It doesn't produce any probabilities to evaluate with a scoring rule. If you're on team Harrell, you should say that SVMs shouldn't be used in the first place, because [non-probabilistic classification is bad](http://www.fharrell.com/2017/01/classification-vs-prediction.html). (Disclaimer: I am not on team Harrell.)

Comment: @Kodiologist I concede that blog post does not bear on SVMs which are not also probability models. But there are still a lot of reasons not to use accuracy, chiefly that it's not connected to any meaningful measurement of quality: the choice of cutoff is arbitrary and context-free and is highly sensitive to class imbalance. It's trivial to construct examples where AUC is 1.0 but accuracy can be made to be anything between 0 and 1 depending on class imbalance. (AUC 1.0 is significant because all positives are ranked higher than negatives, which is exactly what you want in a classifier.)

Comment: But I'm also not an SVM expert. For example, this appears to be a classification task (AUC and accuracy measurements, the target is called "labels"), but OP is using SVM $\epsilon$ regression. Perhaps there's some subtle fact about SVMs that I'm missing.

Comment: @Sycorax Accuracy is itself a measure of model quality and corresponds to 0–1 loss. Under 0–1 loss, the base rate (i.e., degree of class imbalance) is quite important, and hence is reflected in the accuracy. One should choose the cutoff to minimize loss (and hence maximize accuracy), not arbitrarily.

Comment: @Kodiologist All of that is true. I guess I hadn't considered scenarios that care about the base rate in this way, and I'm hard-pressed to imagine one. But that doesn't seem to account for the arbitrariness of the threshold (and adjusting a threshold to some particular end puts you back into the territory of ROC analysis).

Comment: @Sycorax The base rate matters whenever you have to make a binary decision, since the risk of a decision is the sum of the loss associated with each outcome times its probability, and the probabilities are affected by the base rate. (When the losses of both kinds of errors are equal, you have 0–1 loss.)

Comment: Your sample size is too small by perhaps a factor of 20 for the resulting analysis to be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question. The reason is that because of the SVM- Type

```
summary(svm.model)

Call:
svm(formula = train$OVERBILL ~ ., data = train, type = "C", cross = 10, scale = FALSE)

Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  C-classification 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.02173913 

Number of Support Vectors:  148
Number of Classes:  3 

    Levels: 
     0 1 6

    10-fold cross-validation on training data:

    Total Accuracy: 87.16578 
    Single Accuracies:
     94.44444 89.47368 84.21053 88.88889 94.73684 100 66.66667 78.94737 84.21053 89.47368 

conf_matrix

svm_pred  0  1  6
       0 13  0  0
       1  7 19  0
       6  0  0  8
> Accuracy(svm_pred, test_labels)
[1] 0.8510638
> AUC(svm_pred, test_labels)
[1] 0.825
```